# How to read a cookie with NextJs api?

Tags: cookies, next.js

Hi like to read a token cookie with my authentication api in NextJS. So for example my path to the api is like "http://localhost:3005/api/verify .

Yesterday I spent the whole day to find our how I can read a cookie that I wrote before.

I reduced to code for setting the cookie to a minimum to figure out how to read it in the api, but with no success. Also with google searching I found no infos about cookies in NextJS api's.

```
res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie",
        cookie.serialize("token", token, {
          maxAge: 60 * 60,
          path: "/",
        })
      );
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thank in advance
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read cookies via `req.headers.cookie` you do need still to parse them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, meanwhile I found my mistake. I tried req.headers.cookie as well, but it was always empty. My problem was, that I requested the api from server side inside getServerSideProps and then no cookies have been sent to the api.